# Execute command only for specified filetype

Tags: autocmd, filetype-tex

I'm setting up an environment to automatically recompile `.tex` files on save. I've found solution for this:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.tex :! latexmk -pdf
```

But is there any better way to do this? It seems like `*.tex` check will be executed every time I save a file, be it `.c` or `.md` file (maybe I'm wrong about this). Could I possibly place this option somewhere so it is executed only when I save `.tex` files? Something like `ftplugin/tex.vim` (I couldn't make it working there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ftplugin is the right way to go you simply didn't use the right file.

When you open a `test.tex` file and use `set ft?` the result is `plaintex`.

So you need to put your code in `ftplugin/plaintex.vim`

And I would advise to put it in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/plaintex.vim` this way you are sure that you don't override already existing ftplugins.

You might want to read [`:h ftplugin-name`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_05.txt.html#ftplugin-name) and [`:h ftplugin-overrule`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#ftplugin-overrule)

Comment: you are linking twice to the same help section

Comment: Thank you @ChristianBrabandt I fixed it :)

Comment: And then your autocommand can use the special `<buffer>` pattern

Comment: Note also that LaTeX uses `filetype=tex`